# IBM watson conversation no output python

Tags: python, watson-conversation

I have followed the sample examples and created a workspace using IBM watson conversation.

I am using python, and also followed the document api to input the text into watson. However, there is no output as opposed to example.

```
# watson conversation -na service 
import json
from watson_developer_cloud import ConversationV1 as Cv 

conversation =  Cv(username='XXXX',password='XXXX', version='2017-02-03')

# obtain workspace id 
workspace_id = 'Your-ID'
context = {}
response = conversation.message(
  workspace_id=workspace_id,
  message_input={'text': 'hi'},context)

print(json.dumps(response, indent=2))
```

Here is the output of `json.dumps()`:

```
    {
  "output":{
    "text":["hello there, how can i help you?"
    ],
    "nodes_visited":["node_1_1487754696521"
    ],
    "log_messages":[]
  },
  "intents":[{
      "intent":"hello",
      "confidence":0.99
    }
  ],
  "entities":[],
  "input":{
    "text":"hi"
  },
  "context":{
    "system":{
      "_node_output_map":{
        "node_1_1487754696521":[0
        ]
      },
      "dialog_turn_counter":1,
      "dialog_stack":[{
          "dialog_node":"root"
        }
      ],
      "dialog_request_counter":1
    },
    "conversation_id":"b2940af7-73c4-4ca8-81d6-363d18637e8e"
  },
  "alternate_intents":false
}
```

I have tried using the test bot in the workspace and it works. However, there is no output here in python. Does anyone knows what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

i suspect that there can only be one output. Following the sample, I have added a conversation_start that is suppose to trigger after every conversation start.

> "output": { "text": [ "hello there, how can i help you?" ]

I went to my workspace and deleted it. Now it works.

tldr, it only allows 1 output

Comment: 1 output for conversation start? Could you please be more clear

Comment: It seems that it only allows 1 output. I program watson to reply "hello" when i input a "hi". But as you can see above, it gave a ouput of "hello there, how can i help you" which is suppose to output by the bot at the start of any conversation.